# jquery.get(url) synchronization

Tags: javascript, synchronization

OS X 10.6.8, Chrome 15.0.874.121

I'm experiencing an issue with javascript/jquery: I want to download a header file from base url, then add some more text to it and than spit it out to the client. I'm using the following code:

```
var bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder;
$.get('js/header.txt', function(data) {
   bb.append(data);
   console.log("finished reading file");
});
console.log("just before getting the blog");
var blob = bb.getBlob('text/plain');
// append some more 
saveAs(blob,"name.dxf");
```

But that fails because getting the file is only finished way after the `saveAs(blob)` is executed. I know I can fix it with:

```
var bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder;
$.get('js/header.txt', function(data) {
   bb.append(data);
   //append some more
   var blob = bb.getBlob('text/plain');
   saveAs(blob,"name.dxf");
});
```

But that does not really look attractive: I only want to use the `get` statement only to append the header to the blob, and if I want to read a footer from the file system, I have to do a `get` inside a `get`, and spit out the blob in the inner `get`

Are there alternative ways to withhold the code after the get statement from executing until the whole file has been successfully loaded?

Comment: I think this [SO link][1] pretty much answers my question.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.*

But, if you want it to look more attractive, try to describe semantically what you are trying to achieve and then write functions accordingly.  Maybe:

```
function loadBlob (loadHeader, loadBody) {
    loadHeader(loadBody);
}
loadBlob(function (oncomplete) {
    $.get("js/header.txt", function(data) {
        bb.append(data);
        oncomplete();
    });
}, function () {
    var blob = bb.getBlob('text/plain');
    // append some more
    saveAs(blob,"name.dxf");
});
```

I don't know, is that more attractive?  Personally, I find the original just fine, so maybe mine isn't any better, but the point is to use sematics.

* <sup>You could use `setTimeout` to poll and see if the response has been received.  That's *technically* an alternative, but certainly not more attractive, is it?</sup>